# Enable scrolling+paging in ADF table

Tags: oracle-adf

I want to create a table that implements normal paging but I want it to load 100 records per page and allow scrolling to view these records. My table is only big enough to display 18 records, therefore scrolling is desired to view all 100 records and perform bulk update operations.

I've tried scollPolicy="loadMore", but this is not the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

To have pagination on an ADF table when there is more than 100 records you have to :

- Set the **AutoHeightRow** attribute to the number of lines you want your table to display (aka the height of your table) In your case **18**
- set the **scrollPolicy** attribute to **page** so your table is gonna display a pagination for more that 100 rows
- Set the **FetchSize** attribute to how many row you want to preload (in your case 100)(It's better if you set it in your iterator **RangeSize** attribute)

Comment: I tried this solution and it didn't work. I keep getting a table with 18 row pages. I tried tuning my VO to fetch 103 rows as suggested below, but it's the exact same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a View Object, make sure to tune it to support the Range Size. In the VO editor, General Tab, under tuning, set the Fetch to at least three (3) more than Range Size.  In this case it would be 103.